# The C++ web stack, is there one?

Tags: web-development, c++, web-framework

Java would be jsps and servlets (or a framework such as Spring) running on the JVM and tomcat (or glassfish etc).

C# would be asp and C# running on dot.net framework and IIS ? (I have no experience with this please correct and improve my terminology)

Is there an equivalent for C++ ? I could happily call some C++ from a java servlet/controller but was wondering if there are existing frameworks and libraries out there specifically for creating business logic in  C++ with a web front end.

Comment: There are various frameworks for web development in C++ (for example: [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt#/)), but I don't think there's a comprehensive/definitive stack.

Answer (score 6):

C++ have nothing related to networking in it's current standard but there are works in this way.

I would recommand taking a look at:

- [CPPCMS](http://cppcms.com) (which is not a cms but you can build one with)
- [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html) which is a library which will be a proposal to the c++1y standard
- [casablanca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx) (which is not finished yet) which is Microsoft's proposal to C++1y - I don't know if current implementation is cross-platform yet though.

So there is not something as complete as Django for Python or ROR for Ruby yet, but some people in the CPPCMS mailing list said they were working on such kind of framework. CPPCMS is certainly the closest to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I heard some about Wt (www.webtoolkit.eu) and CAS (cas.havoc.ru), but never used them. CAS is used by Yandex internally, as I heard.